# WMS layer is not overlaying exactly when zooming out. How to add WMS layers to google map layer in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

My openlayers code is as follows. But there is shift in between both the layers. How to rectify it?

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map_element',{} );           
        var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Satellite",
            {type: G_HYBRID_MAP, 
             numZoomLevels: 22, 
             isBaseLayer: true, 
             'displayInLayerSwitcher':false},
              {sphericalMercator: true}
            );
        var roads = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Roads", "http://localhost:8088/geoserver/cite/wms",
        {layers: 'cite:viz_roads',
                     isBaseLayer: false,
                     transparent: true, 
                     opacity: 1.0} 
        );

        var org = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "points of interest", "http://localhost:8088/geoserver/cite/wms",
        {layers: 'cite:organisations', 
                     isBaseLayer: false,
                     transparent: true, opacity: 1.0} 
        );
        map.addLayers([gsat,roads,org]);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}));

if(!map.getCenter()){
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(83.324947,17.732909), 14);
}
    }
```

This is the snapshot of the map:

[image]

Observe the shift from position 1 to 2. 1 is the actual position where the feature should be. It is rectified automatically when I turn layer off and on. But how to rectify this error while zooming?

Comment: What is the projection of your map? I don't see you setting it in your code. And what is the projection of your WMS service?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe both are in 900913 projection.